# How can I extract the MD5 hash of a password protected MS Office Word 2000 document?

Tags: hash, md5

AFAIK, the compound file format identifier is D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1, which is located in the offset 0 of the header, which has a length of exactly 512 bytes.

However that is not enough to get the boundaries of the md5 hash of the password. After that I plan to find a preimage in order to recover the document.

Can someone help me please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've downloaded this specification, but I am not sure on how to extract the hash: http://wvware.sourceforge.net/word97.zip

Answer (score 1):

You link the word97 specification for your 2000 document.  I'm not sure if the file format changed, but luckily the encryption is the same.

I don't think you need the md5 hash (if there is one), you just want to break the encryption.  It looks like there are word 97/2000 decryptors on the web (paid or freeware).  My basic google search indicated that it's easier to break the proprietary hash + encryption (partially rc4) than to brute-force the password.

I wasn't going to [link the page](http://www.skynet.ie/%7Ecaolan/Packages/wvDecrypt.html), but it wasn't hard to find.

> Initially a unicode password is taken and some bytes appended, this password is passed through a varient of the standard md5 hash algorithm.
>
> The non standard hash is tricky, and Im far from sure what benefit over standard md5 the modified md5 hash has.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on how to break it, but must not be impossible since there are tools that do it.

I see in this post that a zip crack tool can be used: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Word_Document_%28DOC%29